# Vulkan 18.04 Nvidia 390, not working

Tags: nvidia, vulkan

I am struggling to get vulkan to work.I am using a nvidia GT-550 so I'm limited to 390 driver. I installed it and believe that vulkan should come along with it. Also installed `vulkan-utils` so I could test it but not working.

```
vulkaninfo
/build/vulkan-tools-136mCR/vulkan-tools-1.1.126.0+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:399: failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken, nvidia does not support vulkan on that gpu. Even if the card itself orig. had some limited support the driver doesn't & never will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NVidia GT-550 (Fermi generation) is not compatible with Vulkan. Sorry :)
You can see the compatible versions [here at NVidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver).